# Remove quote from an array in json (Php)

Tags: php, quote

I tryed to remove the quote from my json output, but nothing work...

```
1 => array(

           'y' => str_replace('"','',$behaviour[5]['wcount']),
           'name' => 'Slice Name B'
        ),
```

Output

```
{"y":"3","name":"Slice Name B"}
```

I need to remove the string  `"3"`

I tryed    `str_replace('"','',$behaviour[5]['wcount'])`   and `str_replace("'","",$behaviour[5]['wcount']);`

Someone can help me please ?

Comment: have you tried casting that to an int?

Comment: What about `str_replace(chr(34), '', $behaviour[5]['wcount'])`? Or what @krcko says. Try type casting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
1 => array(
           'y' => intval($behaviour[5]['wcount']),
           'name' => 'Slice Name B'
        ),
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're running PHP 5.3.3. or better, you can pass `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` to `json_encode` which should do what you want:

```
$encoded = json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```